# ¿Esto es una interfaz en java?

Tags: java, poo

Buenas tengo una duda acerca de como veo que a veces declaran variables de una manera que nunca vi , es decir , yo estoy acostumbrado a declarar variables de tipo: `int`, `String`, `double`, `long`, `char`, `float`, etc.
Pero no entiendo cuando declaran así:

```
Codigo codigoDeSeguridad;

jugador jugador1;
```

ya que si lo pongo en eclipse me sale error.

No se si a eso se lo llama interfaz, y si es así, que es una interfaz en java?

Comment: No, eso no es necesariamente una interfaz. `Codigo` o `jugador`, pueden ser clases o interfaces. Con la redacción actual, no me queda claro si quieres preguntar ¿qué es una interfaz?, como dice el título, u otra cosa.

Comment: Solo queria saber que es esto : Codigo codigoDeSeguridad; jugador jugador1; y en caso de ser una interfaz queria saber que era. Pero lo que mas me importa es saber que era esto : Codigo codigoDeSeguridad; jugador jugador1.

Comment: Es una declaración de variable. La variable `codigoDeSeguridad` será de tipo `Codigo`, y `Codigo` a su vez puede ser una clase o una interface. Para saber que es, tendrías que ver su declaración en el código, si lo tienes, o su documentación, si no tienes acceso a los fuentes.

Comment: Gracias , ahora me di cuenta que venia de una clase , por un codigo que me pasaron .Saludos!